# Wordpress wpresidence map points disapear on filter

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I'm currently working on a Wordpress site for a client using Wp Residence and for some odd reason whenever I use a filter on the properties the listing is filtered, but all of the map pins disappear. Any help would be appreciated.

If you use any of the dropdown filters you'll see what I mean, the map is zoomed in over Africa because it's centered with no data points, but zooming out reveals there are no pins at all.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out after getting support from the author. Turns out if your trying to filter properties with dropdowns or query words you have to use the "like" comparison option in the wpresidence "Search" -> "Advanced Search Form" properties.